# Haskell usnig termination in a function

Tags: function, haskell, termination

I would like to know more about termination in functions, for example: how termination work in this function when n is a natural number or how I can terminate this function

```
sum :: Int -> Int
sum 0 = 0
sum n = n + sum (n - 1)
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what your question is? This function will always terminate (ie. return a valid value) if you give it a non-negative integer, because your recursion has a base case and the recursive step always brings the input closer to that.

Comment: check this tutorial: http://learn.hfm.io/recursion/recursion.html

Comment: `sum 0` clearly terminates. Think about what `sum 1` expands to, and you'll quickly see it terminates as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recursion code works like this - there are two clauses, one which defines itself in terms of itself, and one which terminates the calculation by returning a single value. The termination clause here is `sum 0 = 0`, and the definition of `sum` is given by `sum n = n + sum (n-1)`.

You can work it out using pen and paper, for the parameter n = 5:

```
n        sum   
5        5 + sum (4)
         5 + 4 + sum (3)
         5 + 4 + 3 + sum (2)
         5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + sum (1)
         5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 + sum (0)
         5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 + 0
```

Because we specified sum (0) as being 0, the calculation ends here.

The calculation can go wrong and never terminate for a number of reasons:

- There is no termination clause
- The termination clause is never reached

Consider, if you will, the following evil piece of code:

```
badSum :: Int -> Int
badSum 6 = 6
badSum n = n + badSum (n-1)

badSum 5 -- locks up, press Ctrl-C
```

Because the termination clause is never reached, the recursion never terminates. Also, for your `sum` and the illegal value of n = -1.

As an aside, Haskell has two basic integer types, `Int` and `Integer`. The type `Int` is a long integer, whereas `Integer` is a unlimited integer. `Int` is faster, but `Integer` may work better for recursions, particularly in the case where the answer increases very quickly - such as factorials. You have to cast (convert) from one type to the other, as Haskell won't do this for you. In this case, `toInteger` to cast from `Int` to `Integer`, and more generally `fromIntegral`.

```
fact :: Int -> Int
fact 1 = 1
fact n = n * fact (n-1)

fact2 :: Int -> Integer
fact2 1 = 1
fact2 n = (toInteger n) * fact2 (n-1)
```

In both cases, the factorial is defined in terms of itself, with a termination clause of n = 1 resulting in a value of 1. Both do a reasonable job, but for larger n `fact` starts behaving very oddly indeed:

```
 n      fact                   fact2
 1                    1                              1
 5                  120                            120
10              3628800                        3628800
20  2432902008176640000            2432902008176640000
30   -8764578968847253504          265252859812191058636308480000000
```

Because `Int` is a fixed length integer, eventually the value will wrap around, in this case producing a negative value.

Finally, real-world Haskell wouldn't use a recursion like that. There is a sum function which your code has temporarily replaced. The sum from 1 to n is given  by `sum [1 .. n]`, and the factorial is given by `product [1 .. n]`.